# Filter Data , Copy Changed status and update in another file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 Excel files

1. [Tracker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMKQq.png)
2. [Inventory file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rFag.png)

I would like to filter only change in Column G "Changes"

copy the Changed Group Name's "**Renewal Status Detail**" from Tracker file to Inventory file's **Renewal status** detail field

using VBA code,

How can i achieve this could some one help me out please .

Basically Status changes in tracker file from tracker file to that respective group we update the statuses in Inventory file

```
Option Explicit

Sub Lookup()

    Dim rnge As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Workbooks("Trackers 040820 PM.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets("Central").Activate

    With Worksheets("Central").Range("A1:G1")
        .AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="Change"
    End With


    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    'set rnge = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

        For Each cell In Selection
        'If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then

            srchval = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
            chgval = ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value

            On Error Resume Next

            Workbooks("Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx").Activate

            get_row_number = Sheets("Main Data input").Range("D:D").Find( _
              What:=srchval, _
              LookIn:=xlValues, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=True _
              ).Row

            If get_row_number = "" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                Workbooks("Interim Inventory Tracker - All States 040620 v1.xlsx").Activate
                Sheets("Main Data input").Range("H" & get_row_number).Value = chgval
                Workbooks("Trackers 040820 PM.xlsx").Activate
                chgval = ""
            End If
        'End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There's plenty of examples in SO of how to filter, copy, paste, and cook data between workbooks and sheets. You just google it, do your trial and error and eventually come back here with your code and its issues (if any)

Comment: I tried, couldn't find this scenario, i am very new to excel .

Comment: So what's the issue with your code?